# how to make password regex standards for validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

ı am looking for a regex code which can control at least 1 number when entering password.
ı am using this

```
     var rakamKontrol = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[0-9])$/);
     if (!rakamKontrol.test(r.newPassword)) {
                        alert("at least 1 number ..");

//but even ı enter number for password ı got error alert.


                }
```

ı also try to
at least one special character,
at least one upper case ,
at least one lower case ,
at least 8 characters.
and ı want to show error messsages unique.
for lower case,for upper case etc.

Comment: A regexp of `/^.*\d.*$/` would match any string so long as there was at least one digit any where in it

Comment: To check for at least one number ```numberRegEx = new RegExp(/[0-9/);```

Comment: Why not just `if (/\d/.test(r.newPassword)) { alert("at least 1 number"); }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following set of tests include everything you mentioned. Using HereticMonkeys syntax just because it looks good.

regex 101 https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

```
if(!/\d/.test(r.newPassword)){
    console.log('A password must contain at least one number');
}
if(!/[a-z]/.test(r.newPassword)){
    console.log('A password must contain at least lower case letter');
}
if(!/[A-Z]/.test(r.newPassword)){
    console.log('A password must contain at least upper case letter');
}
if(!/[!#=@$%&*)(_-]/.test(r.newPassword)){
    console.log('A password must contain at least one special character');
}
if(r.newPassword.length < 8){
    console.log('A password must be at least 8 characters long');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`password-validator`](https://github.com/tarunbatra/password-validator) library for defining your password rules. Eg:

```js
var passwordValidator = require('password-validator');
var schema = new passwordValidator();

schema
  .has().digits()
  .has().uppercase()

const failedRules = schema.validate(r.newPassword, {list: true});

if (failedRules.includes('digits') {
  alert('at least 1 number ..')
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of [password-validator](https://github.com/tarunbatra/password-validator).